# How to match multiple urls to same location using regex

Tags: nginx

I need to match

- http://local.com/#app
- http://local.com/app

to the same subdirectory.

Trying to put regex in the location. But it's not working at all.
Any idea?

```
server {
  server_name local;
  location ^~ /(.*)app {
    alias   /var/www/app;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I think `location ~* ^/(*)app{` should work?

Comment: @BijayRegmi thanks for ur suggestion. But doesn't work. 404 I got. lol~~nginx is so confusing. The regex way thinking is just ```/(.*)app```

Comment: `#app` is a URI fragment and is never received by Nginx - so Nginx cannot do anything with that.

Comment: @RichardSmith if so, can we at least rewrite **/#app** to **/app** in Nginx

Comment: @newBike you can't. NGINX, nor any web server, never see the URI fragment. It is only "seen" on the browser side, e.g. by Javascript code executed on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything after # is not processed by web server. So this would not work at the NGINX level.  But what you can do is at the backend, where will be serving "/" files, like if you are using NodeJS or Python, you can easily redirect `http://local.com/#app` to `http://local.com/app`